# How to close a terminal window using Apple Script

Tags: bash, applescript

### Background

I am using a combination of *AppleScript* and *Bash* to create a program that launches a set of commands in `Terminal.app` then closes that window when it terminates.

`terminal.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
#     terminal                   Opens the current directory in a new terminal window
#     terminal [PATH]            Open PATH in a new terminal window
#     terminal [CMD]             Open a new terminal window and execute CMD
#     terminal [PATH] [CMD]      Opens a new terminal window @ the PATH and executes CMD
#
# Example:
#     terminal ~/Code/HelloWorld ./setup.sh

[ "$(uname -s)" != "Darwin" ] && {
    echo 'Mac OS Only'
    return
}

function terminal() {
    local cmd=""
    local wd="$PWD"
    local args="$*"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        wd="$1"
        args="${*:2}"
    fi

    if [ -n "$args" ]; then
        cmd="$args"
    fi

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell window 1
        do script "cd $wd ; $cmd"
        repeat while busy
            delay 1
        end repeat
        my close()
    end tell
end tell

on close()
    activate application "Terminal"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Terminal"
            keystroke "w" using {command down}
        end tell
    end tell
end close
EOF
}

terminal "$@"
```

### Issue

Currently, the AppleScript does not close the window when the script itself completes.

Comment: @user3439894 Very good point! Deleted my comment (and upvoted your excellent answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your *code* into an empty *file*, saved it and made it executable.

I then ran it in **Terminal** and received the following error:

```
 175:183: syntax error: A command name can’t go after this “my”. (-2740)
```

I then changed the name of the `close()` *handler* to `closeWindow()` and the *script* worked as desired.

Note that `close` is a built-in **AppleScript** *command* and cannot be used as the *name* of a *handler*

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using `System Events` because this requires accessibility permissions? I was thinking about modifying `com.apple.terminal shellExitAction` to 0 instead of 2 which closes the window on `exit`, but it doesn't actually update the preferences when `default write com.apple.terminal shellExitAction -int 0` for the current terminal window.

Comment: @Nicholas Adamou, I'm running **macOS High Sierra** and do not have **Terminal** or **System Events** in **Accessibility** permissions and it works fine for me in that it is actually closing the _window_ it opened after the _command_ passed to the executable runs.  That said, the `shellExitAction` _key_ is not a _global_ **Terminal** setting but one at the _profile_ level, so if you setting it e.g. `defaults write com.apple.terminal shellExitAction -int 0` it's not going to work.  If you make this change from the **Terminal** > **Preferences…** it works immediately.

Comment: Yeah, I am running the latest version of macOS `10.15.2` Catalina and it will ask for permissions upon doing it this way. I am trying to find a way to do this without having to manually open **Terminal** > **Preferences** > **Profiles** > **Shell**. Even running `sudo defaults write com.apple.terminal shellExitAction -int 0` doesn't affect it because the preferences are cached apparently.

Comment: @Nicholas Adamou, Caching isn't the immediate issue as `defaults write com.apple.terminal shellExitAction -int 0` is not valid because `shellExitAction` is not a _global key_ in **Terminal**, it's set under the `Window Settings` _key_ under the _name of the profile key_. In some cases, using `; killall cfprefsd` after a properly formed `defaults write` _command_ will force the change to update. You may have to use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to change/set the _value_ of a _nested key_. It probably also can be done with `defaults` but getting the _syntax_ for a _multi-level nested key_ isn't easy

Comment: @Nicholas Adamou, In other words, if you remove everything from the _output_ of `defaults read com.apple.terminal` not relevant to the `shellExitAction` _key_, its hierarchy is, e.g., `{ "Window Settings" = { "Basic" = { shellExitAction = 2; }; }; }` not `{ shellExitAction = 2 }`, the latter would be a _global key_ in **Terminal**  but the `shellExitAction` _key_ is not a _global key_ in **Terminal**. `{ "Default Window Settings" = "Basic"; }` is a _global key_.

Comment: Okay, I see, So, how would the `defaults write` command go for modifying `shellExitAction` or `plistBuddy`?

Comment: @Nicholas Adamou, All of this in these comments really is beyond the _scope_ of the original question that you asked and I answered.  I'd suggest you do a bit of research and when you can't figure it out, post a new question to try and resolve this separate issue. Don't forget to include the research you've done and what you already tried that didn't work.

Comment: I had success with `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :Window\ Settings:Basic:shellExitAction 1" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` thanks to this thread :)